# Python - Pandas: Find largests values off-diagonal

Tags: python, pandas

This is somewhat complicated. I have multiple dataframes `df`, all with the same columns and index that looks like the one below:

```
       E          F          H            
row                                                                     
CE     17.917153 10.875160   9.970251 
CF     9.780500  16.261098  10.021619    
CH     12.293967 10.608844  10.870527
```

My objective in each `df` is to find the **two** maximum values in the dataframe and their corresponding `index` and `column`. These max values **cannot be on the diagonal** . How can I do so?

Comment: **off-diagonal** ???

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Any two max values that I extract from `df` cannot be in the index (CE, E), (CF, F), and (CH, H).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pandas import *


L = [[17.917153, 10.875160,   9.970251],   
     [9.780500,  16.261098,  10.021619], 
     [12.293967, 10.608844,  10.870527]]

df = DataFrame(L)

df2 = df.unstack().copy()

df2.sort()

IDX = df2[:].index

IDX = list(reversed(IDX))


M = []

for x in IDX[1:]:
    if(x[0]==x[1]):
        continue
    M.append(x);
    if(len(M)==2):
        break;

Max1 = M[0]
Max2 = M[1]


print "Max1 : ", Max1, "->", df2[Max1] 
print "Max2 : ", Max2, "->", df2[Max2]
```

Output:

```
Max1 :  (0, 2) -> 12.293967
Max2 :  (1, 0) -> 10.87516
         ^
       column
```

Comment: I see but the first max you get is on the diagonal. 17.917153 is (CE, E). My maximum values cannot be on the diagonal.

Comment: So could we for `df2` simply remove all levels = multilabel, so remove (0,0), (1,1), and (2,2)? That would take care of remove the diagonal elements.

Comment: No.. You have to ignore diagonal.. Now check my answer.. Hope it will help

Comment: Wait ... 10.87516 is also on the diagonal ... (CH, H) thanks for the help

Comment: 10.875160  is not in diagonal  (CE,F)

Comment: 10.875160 .. not 10.870527.. ok?